# Mantaining Certificates in Tomcat 6 to avoid end user to add an exception on browser

Tags: browser, tomcat6, ssl-certificate

What do I need to configure in Tomcat6 which will prevent user from adding an exception on browser when they access my website?
The case with me is that every time a new user is accessing my website then the add an exception page comes up and I do not need this. Kindly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSL certificate that you install in your tomcat must be signed by a Certificate Authority that your browser recognizes as trusted.
Meaning that you have two possibilities:
1) Let your server-side certificate be signed by a known Certificate Authority like [Verisign](http://www.verisigninc.com/), this will cost you some money
2) Create an own Certificate Authority and 'distribute' it to your clients which will have to install it in their browser as trusted CA